# how to display a list from js on html page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a js file and list in this. then i go to another page by click on a button (html) where i want to display this list in `<ul>`. Pls help

I tried this but I don't understand what i should do on the html page to make this work
here in the very first strings i try to import the list and then send it to the html

list.js:

```
let list = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
let input = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
let form = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
let priority = document.querySelector('.todo-priority');
flag = false;
const isImportant = () => {
  return priority.classList.contains('is-important');
}

priority.onclick = function() {
  priority.classList.toggle('is-important');
  if (isImportant() && !flag) {
    priority.textContent = 'Задача на один день';
    flag = true;
    priority.classList.toggle('is-important');
  } else if (isImportant() && flag) {
    priority.textContent = 'Важная задача';
    flag = false;
    isImportant = () => false;
  } else {
    priority.textContent = 'Повторяющаяся задача';
  }
};

form.onsubmit = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const newTask = document.createElement('li');
  newTask.textContent = input.value;
  if (isImportant()) {
    newTask.classList.add('is-important');
  }
  list.append(newTask);

  input.value = '';
};

// export const arr = list;
// exports.array = list;
```

dragANDdrop.js

```
import { list } from "./list.js";

const html = list.map((item) => `<li>${item}</li>`).join('');
document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = dragANDdrop.html;


const tasksListElement = document.querySelector(`.tasks__list`);
const taskElements = tasksListElement.querySelectorAll(`.tasks__item`);
```

Comment: Variables are not shared between different pages. Use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` to pass data between pages.

Comment: thanks for the advice but i need little help. i did this: list.js localStorage.setItem('lst', list); dragANDdrop.js list = localStorage.getItem('lst');

const html = list.map((item) => `<li>${item}</li>`).join('');
document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = html;               but still it doesnt work. could u help pls? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the list variable in your list.js file.

```
export let list = [];
let input = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
let form = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
let priority = document.querySelector('.todo-priority');
let flag = false;

const isImportant = () => {
  return priority.classList.contains('is-important');
}

priority.onclick = function() {
  priority.classList.toggle('is-important');
  if (isImportant() && !flag) {
    priority.textContent = 'Задача на один день';
    flag = true;
    priority.classList.toggle('is-important');
  } else if (isImportant() && flag) {
    priority.textContent = 'Важная задача';
    flag = false;
    isImportant = () => false;
  } else {
    priority.textContent = 'Повторяющаяся задача';
  }
};

form.onsubmit = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const newTask = document.createElement('li');
  newTask.textContent = input.value;
  if (isImportant()) {
    newTask.classList.add('is-important');
  }
  list.push(input.value); // Push the new task into the list array
  input.value = '';
};
```

You should import the list from list.js into dragANDdrop.js.

```
import { list } from "./list.js";

const html = list.map((item) => `<li>${item}</li>`).join('');
document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = html; // corrected variable name

// Other drag and drop functionalities if needed
```

You need to have an HTML file where you display the list

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul></ul> <!-- This is where your list will be displayed -->

  <script src="list.js"></script>
  <script src="dragANDdrop.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you a lot! but when i add  list.push(input.value); the button stops working. can i do anything with that?

Comment: One possible reason could be that input.value is not being set properly , you can add some console.log statements to see